# apache2 refusing to start

Tags: apache2

When i try to start **apache2** this error message returns

````
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.```

**systemctl status apache2.service**
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2019-07-09 09:11:20 CEST; 2min 44s ago
     Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
  Process: 11763 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

jul 09 09:11:20 vek-ubuntu apachectl[11763]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this mes
jul 09 09:11:20 vek-ubuntu apachectl[11763]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
jul 09 09:11:20 vek-ubuntu apachectl[11763]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
jul 09 09:11:20 vek-ubuntu apachectl[11763]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
jul 09 09:11:20 vek-ubuntu apachectl[11763]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
jul 09 09:11:20 vek-ubuntu apachectl[11763]: Action 'start' failed.
jul 09 09:11:20 vek-ubuntu apachectl[11763]: The Apache error log may have more information.
jul 09 09:11:20 vek-ubuntu systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
jul 09 09:11:20 vek-ubuntu systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
jul 09 09:11:20 vek-ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.

**journalctl -xe**
jul 09 09:13:05 vek-ubuntu dhclient[11812]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x992da85e)
jul 09 09:13:08 vek-ubuntu dhclient[11812]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x992da85e)
jul 09 09:13:11 vek-ubuntu dhclient[11812]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4 (xid=0x992da85e)
jul 09 09:13:12 vek-ubuntu kernel: r8169 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: rtl_txcfg_empty_cond == 0 (loop: 666, delay: 100).
jul 09 09:13:15 vek-ubuntu dhclient[11812]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4 (xid=0x992da85e)
jul 09 09:13:19 vek-ubuntu dhclient[11812]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9 (xid=0x992da85e)
jul 09 09:13:28 vek-ubuntu dhclient[11812]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 21 (xid=0x992da85e)
jul 09 09:13:50 vek-ubuntu dhclient[11812]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14 (xid=0x992da85e)
jul 09 09:13:50 vek-ubuntu NetworkManager[1308]: <warn>  [1562656430.1354] dhcp4 (enp4s0): request timed out
jul 09 09:13:50 vek-ubuntu NetworkManager[1308]: <info>  [1562656430.1355] dhcp4 (enp4s0): state changed unknown -> timeout
jul 09 09:13:50 vek-ubuntu NetworkManager[1308]: <info>  [1562656430.1522] dhcp4 (enp4s0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 11812
jul 09 09:13:50 vek-ubuntu NetworkManager[1308]: <info>  [1562656430.1523] dhcp4 (enp4s0): state changed timeout -> done
jul 09 09:13:50 vek-ubuntu NetworkManager[1308]: <info>  [1562656430.1530] device (enp4s0): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jul 09 09:13:50 vek-ubuntu NetworkManager[1308]: <warn>  [1562656430.1547] device (enp4s0): Activation: failed for connection 'Trådbunden anslutning 1'
jul 09 09:13:50 vek-ubuntu NetworkManager[1308]: <info>  [1562656430.1554] device (enp4s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jul 09 09:13:50 vek-ubuntu avahi-daemon[1302]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::37d5:905b:6570:1eaa on enp4s0.
jul 09 09:13:50 vek-ubuntu avahi-daemon[1302]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp4s0.IPv6 with address fe80::37d5:905b:6570:1eaa.
jul 09 09:13:50 vek-ubuntu avahi-daemon[1302]: Interface enp4s0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
jul 09 09:13:50 vek-ubuntu NetworkManager[1308]: <info>  [1562656430.1588] policy: auto-activating connection 'Trådbunden anslutning 1' (4aaddc78-ded2-3c3d-820d-51833c7b4b11)
jul 09 09:13:50 vek-ubuntu NetworkManager[1308]: <info>  [1562656430.1593] device (enp4s0): Activation: starting connection 'Trådbunden anslutning 1' (4aaddc78-ded2-3c3d-820d-51833c7b4b11)
jul 09 09:13:50 vek-ubuntu NetworkManager[1308]: <info>  [1562656430.1595] device (enp4s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jul 09 09:13:50 vek-ubuntu NetworkManager[1308]: <info>  [1562656430.1599] device (enp4s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jul 09 09:13:50 vek-ubuntu NetworkManager[1308]: <info>  [1562656430.1603] device (enp4s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jul 09 09:13:50 vek-ubuntu NetworkManager[1308]: <info>  [1562656430.1607] dhcp4 (enp4s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
jul 09 09:13:50 vek-ubuntu NetworkManager[1308]: <info>  [1562656430.1621] dhcp4 (enp4s0): dhclient started with pid 11868
jul 09 09:13:50 vek-ubuntu avahi-daemon[1302]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp4s0.IPv6 with address fe80::37d5:905b:6570:1eaa.
jul 09 09:13:50 vek-ubuntu avahi-daemon[1302]: New relevant interface enp4s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
jul 09 09:13:50 vek-ubuntu avahi-daemon[1302]: Registering new address record for fe80::37d5:905b:6570:1eaa on enp4s0.*.
jul 09 09:13:50 vek-ubuntu dhclient[11868]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x4b037477)
jul 09 09:13:53 vek-ubuntu dhclient[11868]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0x4b037477)
jul 09 09:14:00 vek-ubuntu dhclient[11868]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10 (xid=0x4b037477)
jul 09 09:14:02 vek-ubuntu kernel: r8169 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: rtl_txcfg_empty_cond == 0 (loop: 666, delay: 100).
jul 09 09:14:10 vek-ubuntu dhclient[11868]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 20 (xid=0x4b037477)
jul 09 09:14:30 vek-ubuntu dhclient[11868]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10 (xid=0x4b037477)
jul 09 09:14:35 vek-ubuntu NetworkManager[1308]: <warn>  [1562656475.1356] dhcp4 (enp4s0): request timed out
jul 09 09:14:35 vek-ubuntu NetworkManager[1308]: <info>  [1562656475.1357] dhcp4 (enp4s0): state changed unknown -> timeout
jul 09 09:14:35 vek-ubuntu NetworkManager[1308]: <info>  [1562656475.1683] dhcp4 (enp4s0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 11868
jul 09 09:14:35 vek-ubuntu NetworkManager[1308]: <info>  [1562656475.1684] dhcp4 (enp4s0): state changed timeout -> done
jul 09 09:14:35 vek-ubuntu NetworkManager[1308]: <info>  [1562656475.1691] device (enp4s0): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jul 09 09:14:35 vek-ubuntu NetworkManager[1308]: <warn>  [1562656475.1705] device (enp4s0): Activation: failed for connection 'Trådbunden anslutning 1'
jul 09 09:14:35 vek-ubuntu NetworkManager[1308]: <info>  [1562656475.1712] device (enp4s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jul 09 09:14:35 vek-ubuntu avahi-daemon[1302]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::37d5:905b:6570:1eaa on enp4s0.
jul 09 09:14:35 vek-ubuntu avahi-daemon[1302]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp4s0.IPv6 with address fe80::37d5:905b:6570:1eaa.
jul 09 09:14:35 vek-ubuntu avahi-daemon[1302]: Interface enp4s0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
jul 09 09:14:35 vek-ubuntu NetworkManager[1308]: <info>  [1562656475.1744] policy: auto-activating connection 'Trådbunden anslutning 1' (4aaddc78-ded2-3c3d-820d-51833c7b4b11)
jul 09 09:14:35 vek-ubuntu NetworkManager[1308]: <info>  [1562656475.1750] device (enp4s0): Activation: starting connection 'Trådbunden anslutning 1' (4aaddc78-ded2-3c3d-820d-51833c7b4b11)
jul 09 09:14:35 vek-ubuntu NetworkManager[1308]: <info>  [1562656475.1751] device (enp4s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jul 09 09:14:35 vek-ubuntu NetworkManager[1308]: <info>  [1562656475.1756] device (enp4s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jul 09 09:14:35 vek-ubuntu NetworkManager[1308]: <info>  [1562656475.1760] device (enp4s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jul 09 09:14:35 vek-ubuntu NetworkManager[1308]: <info>  [1562656475.1763] dhcp4 (enp4s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
jul 09 09:14:35 vek-ubuntu NetworkManager[1308]: <info>  [1562656475.1776] dhcp4 (enp4s0): dhclient started with pid 11895
jul 09 09:14:35 vek-ubuntu avahi-daemon[1302]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp4s0.IPv6 with address fe80::37d5:905b:6570:1eaa.
jul 09 09:14:35 vek-ubuntu avahi-daemon[1302]: New relevant interface enp4s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
jul 09 09:14:35 vek-ubuntu avahi-daemon[1302]: Registering new address record for fe80::37d5:905b:6570:1eaa on enp4s0.*.
jul 09 09:14:35 vek-ubuntu dhclient[11895]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xe6c8bb5e)
jul 09 09:14:38 vek-ubuntu dhclient[11895]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0xe6c8bb5e)
````

Comment: There is another process listening on port TCP/80. Please, post `sudo netstat -napo | grep ":80 .* LISTEN"` output in your original question.